# Problems installing DBD::mysql in Perl

Tags: mysql, database, perl, cpan, dbi

i'm trying to make a perl script that interacts with my mysql database within my *AMP stack, but i'm having some problems. I have installed the DBI module but when i try to install the DBD:mysql driver it just keeps failing. I have tried to force the install too but that didn't work either.

I have been using the 'install DBD:mysql' command while in cpan in the terminal. Any help would be brilliant.

Comment: `install DBD:mysql` or `install DBD::mysql` ?

Comment: install DBD::mysql, sorry that's a typo!

Comment: Ok so i have tried to take another approach, i found a link that says if i just use ppm to install the mysql specific DBD:mysqlPP module that i can avoid these troubles. Has anyone used this successfully? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: What OS are you using? What error are you getting? You need to provide some actual information if you want any actual help! We are not psychic (well, I'm not anyway) :)

Comment: I'm really sorry, i fixed this problem and completely forgot i asked this question. It was solved by using a different module called DBI:mysqlPP, which was painfully easy to get working after the days i had spent trying to make DBD::mysql work! Hopefully this helps anyone with a similar problem! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided us with the error messages that you have stumbled upon, I guess the problem is that you have not installed MySQL client libraries and header files.

Quoting [`DBD::mysql`](http://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql):

> However, you need at least the client libraries and possibly the
>   header files, if you are compiling [`DBD::mysql`](http://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql) from source.

Comment: i'm sorry, i should have also mentioned i am on Snow Leopard. I will get the errors posted up now, thanks.